# RxJs Return old value when when filter return false

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

The main purpose of this code is to check if values exist in store and prevent additional request to server. Whole logic works fine but unfortunately when filter returns false selector is not applied to observable and array is empty even if values are in store.

```
  this.events$ = this.paginationService.page$.pipe(
      switchMap(pageIndex => this.store.pipe(
        delay(0),

        //get objects from store
        select(selectEventsPageByGenre(this.musicGenre, { pageIndex: pageIndex, pageSize: 3 })),

        //if there are no objects from select() the dispatch server request
        filter(events => events.length === 0),
        map(() => {
          this.store.dispatch(new EventsPageRequested({
            musicGenre: MusicGenre[this.musicGenre.toUpperCase()],
            page: {
              pageIndex: pageIndex,
              pageSize: 6
            }
          }));

          return [];
        })
      ))
    );
```

How to return values from selector when filter returns false (if array is not empty)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `filter()`, and replace the `map()` by

```
    map(() => {
      if (events.length > 0) {
        return events;
      }
      this.store.dispatch(new EventsPageRequested({
        musicGenre: MusicGenre[this.musicGenre.toUpperCase()],
        page: {
          pageIndex: pageIndex,
          pageSize: 6
        }
      }));

      return [];
    })
```